# Using RPi as DAQ for PC

Tags: python, communication, sockets

I am quite new to using RPi, but my experience has been great so far. I am hoping to achieve just one more thing.

I have 4 ADCs hooked up to my RPi using I2C, and I am sampling at roughly 800 - 1000 Hz from each ADC individually. I would like to process the sampled data real-time by passing it to PC, where I have a GUI display to show all the processed data.

I also have a camera and I would like to record images at 5 fps, which would also be displayed on the PC GUI.

I would like to reliably let the Pi and PC communicate information (which is quite lightweight as I plan to use low resolution, low sampling rate). I am using python on both systems and I've seen people say that **TCP using socket module on python** is a good way to do what I would like to do. I just want to know what's the "standard" in doing DAQ/data processing as in my current setup.

I apologize ahead of time if my question is lacking in details, but please let me know and I will be happy to provide more information if needed.